# char (contain words) array buble sort problem (c)

Tags: c, char, bubble-sort, cpu-word

Outputs is error in C.
İf you do compile and run doesnt sort words in array. My C info is very few. Can you see my wrong on my codes?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct node {
   char data;
   int key;
   struct node *next;
};


struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *current = NULL;

//display the list
void printList() {
   struct node *ptr = head;
   printf("\n");

   //start from the beginning
   while(ptr != NULL) {
      printf("(%d -> %c)",ptr->key,ptr->data);
      printf("\n");
      ptr = ptr->next;
   }
}

//insert link at the first location
void insertFirst(int key, char data) {
   //create a link

   struct node *link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

   link->key = key;
   link->data = data;

   //point it to old first node
   link->next = head;

   //point first to new first node
   head = link;
}

//is list empty
bool isEmpty() {
   return head == NULL;
}

int length() {
   int length = 0;
   struct node *current;

   for(current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
      length++;
   }

   return length;
}

void buble_sort() {

   int i, j, k, tempKey;
   char tempData;
   struct node *current;
   struct node *next;

   int size = length();
   k = size ;

   for ( i = 0 ; i < size - 1 ; i++, k-- ) {
      current = head;
      next = head->next;

      for ( j = 1 ; j < k ; j++ ) {   

         if ( current->data > next->data ) {
            tempData = current->data;
            current->data = next->data;
            next->data = tempData;

            tempKey = current->key;
            current->key = next->key;
            next->key = tempKey;
         }

         current = current->next;
         next = next->next;
      }
   }   
}    

void main() {
   insertFirst(1,"Papatya");
   insertFirst(2,"DortKardes");
   insertFirst(3,"Toroslu");
   insertFirst(4,"PostEdu");
   insertFirst(5,"Adana");

   buble_sort();

   printf("Buble Sort ile Siralanmis Hali : ");
   printList();
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled and treat the warnings as errors. I get 10 warnings that are rather errors. You're mixing up `char` and `char*`.

Comment: Your struct ad your insert function want `char data`, but you pass string literals, which are `char *`. Do what Jabberwocky suggests and the compiler will tell you so.

Comment: In C char format specified is %c and for the string it’s %s. You can dynamically allocated the size of char using malloc() and make sure to free() or use array.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about pointers and work with strings in c.

As mentioned in comments. To contain string you should use char *.

Here is example of working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct node {
   char *data;
   int key;
   struct node *next;
};


struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *current = NULL;

//display the list
void printList() {
   struct node *ptr = head;
   printf("\n");

   //start from the beginning
   while(ptr != NULL) {
      printf("(%d -> %s)",ptr->key,ptr->data);
      printf("\n");
      ptr = ptr->next;
   }
}

//insert link at the first location
void insertFirst(int key, char *data) {
   //create a link

   struct node *link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

   link->key = key;
   link->data = data;

   //point it to old first node
   link->next = head;

   //point first to new first node
   head = link;
}

//is list empty
bool isEmpty() {
   return head == NULL;
}

int length() {
   int length = 0;
   struct node *current;

   for(current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
      length++;
   }

   return length;
}

void buble_sort() {

   int i, j, k, tempKey;
   char *tempData = NULL;
   struct node *current;
   struct node *next;

   int size = length();
   k = size ;

   for ( i = 0 ; i < size - 1 ; i++, k-- ) {
      current = head;
      next = head->next;

      for ( j = 1 ; j < k ; j++ ) {   

      if ( strcmp(current->data, next->data) > 0 ) {
            tempData = current->data;
            current->data = next->data;
            next->data = tempData;

            tempKey = current->key;
            current->key = next->key;
            next->key = tempKey;
         }

         current = current->next;
         next = next->next;
      }
   }   
}    

void main() {
   insertFirst(1,"Papatya");
   insertFirst(2,"DortKardes");
   insertFirst(4,"PostEdu");
   insertFirst(5,"Adana");
   insertFirst(3,"Toroslu");

   buble_sort();

   printf("Buble Sort ile Siralanmis Hali : ");
   printList();
}
```

Comment: Also simply copying the pointers to the strings into the structure is certainly a very bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for all. Only buble sort method doesnt sort A ->Z array. I look to this.

Comment: Please copy code again. I've fixe your sort. Just need to change current->data > next->data to current->key > next->key.

Comment: @KurokawaMasato apparently it works after your edit. But my second comment still stands. You should duplicate the strings before copying the pointers into the struct, or have something like `char data[100]` instead of `char *data`  and use `strcpy`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks for correcting me :) 
I've pasted an old code, that stored in buffer.

Comment: I copied to my editor your code now. But still this sorting with key.

Comment: Wrong 1-2-3-4-5. Must be sorted by words.

Comment: @JüpiterYazılım My bad. Change `if ( current->data > next->data ) {` to 
`if ( strcmp(current->data, next->data) > 0 ) {`
Already fixed it in code above.

Comment: Perfect perfect perfect. Thanks for all to everybody. You are perfect. <3

Comment: @Jabberwocky About your second comment. It's not a bad idea, until you will have tried to free it. I don't know what OP try to achieve, so I just fix the code. In most cases you would right.

Comment: @KurokawaMasato yes, your answer fixes the OP's code, but storing just the pointers to the strings may yield in "surprising" results if you store for example the pointer to some local variuable that later goes out of scope. In this case it's OK because you're storing pointers to string literals and latter are immutable.